# Show a prime number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, mathematical-french

> Let $ n $ be a natural integer strictly greater than $ 1 $.
>
> If $ n $ is not prime, it admits a prime divisor less than or equal to $ \sqrt {n} $.

How can I write an assertion expressing the above proposition. thank you

Let $\mathcal{P} $ be the set of prime numbers.

$$ (\forall n>1)\quad n\notin\mathcal{P} \implies \exists\; p\in\mathcal{P}, \begin{cases}p\leq \sqrt{n} \\ p\mid n \end{cases}$$

Its contraposition

$$(\forall n>1)\quad \forall\; p\in\mathcal{P}, \begin{cases}p> \sqrt{n} \\\rm{Or}\\ p\nmid n \end{cases}\implies   n \in\mathcal{P} $$

Doing the contraposition does not lead me to find the same point method:

> To show that a natural number $n\geq 2$ is prime, it suffices to check
>   That it is not divisible by any integer $k$ satisfying $2 \leq k \leq \sqrt{n}$.

[image]

Comment: The $p>\sqrt n$ tells you to stop looking after you have exceeded $\sqrt n$. The $p \nmid n$ tells you to check that it is not divisible by any integer within.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this:
$$(\forall n>1)\quad \forall\; p\in\mathcal{P}, \begin{cases}p> \sqrt{n} \\\rm{Or}\\ p\nmid n \end{cases}\implies   n \in\mathcal{P} $$

To check whether $n$ is prime, you have to prove that for every prime $p$, at least one of the two listed conditions holds. For all primes larger than $\sqrt{n}$, the condition $p> \sqrt{n}$ obviously holds. For the remaining primes, i.e. the primes in the range $2 \le p \le \sqrt{n}$ that condition is false, so for those you need the other condition $p\nmid n$ to be true. If that condition is true for all primes in this range, then the whole statement is true for all primes and $n$ is prime.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation.

Comment: Could you suggest me some books that explain elementary number theory as you do